# Javascript ESLint Error - Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Currently have an issue with respect to ESLint picking up an error with ternery operators which is

> Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression.

My code is as follows:

```
<div style={style}><DatePicker label="From" disabled={value === 'custom' ? true : false} /></div>
<div style={style}><DatePicker label="To" disabled={value === 'custom' ? true : false } /></div>
```

What is the best way to write this to prevent ESLink picking up the following error.

Comment: All you need is `value === custom` because `===` yields either `true` or `false`. No need for the `? :`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply write `disabled={value === 'custom'}`.

`value === 'custom'` will already return true or false, no need to test if true then return true. ;-)